# How to import prebuilt intent from dialogflow to rasa

Tags: dialogflow-es, spacy, rasa-nlu

I have imported a dialogflow project to rasa, but in my entities, I got some prebuilt dialogflow entities like this one :

[image]

then, in my fieldValue2_entries_fr.json file, I have :

```
[
  {
    "value": "@sys.street-address:street",
    "synonyms": [
      "@sys.street-address:street"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "@sys.email:mail",
    "synonyms": [
      "@sys.email:mail"
    ]
  }
]
```

I have no idea how rasa could know about "@sys.email", so I suppose we cannot use it this way right ?

May I replace it with SpaCy prébuilt entities? But How?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ner_duckling` [component](http://nlu.rasa.ai/pipeline.html#ner-duckling) for extracting emails and `ner_spacy` [component](http://nlu.rasa.ai/pipeline.html#ner-duckling) for extracting the address.

These extractors are pre-trained so you don't have to label the entities in your training data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it!